# Implementing Deferred Location Updates in iOS

Tags: ios, gps, location, cllocationmanager, battery-saver

I am trying to implement the **Deferred Location Updates** functionality in my iOS app. I understand that this feature significantly reduces the power consumption of location-aware apps that use GPS. Apple's documentation shows the following code as an example:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
   [self.run addLocations:locations];
   if (!self.deferringUpdates) {
      CLLocationDistance distance = self.hike.goal - self.hike.distance;
      NSTimeInterval time = [self.nextAudible timeIntervalSinceNow];
      [locationManager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:distance
                                                     timeout:time];
   self.deferringUpdates = YES;
   }
}
```

However, when I start typing `if (!self.d`... the "deferringUpdates" property does not show up. Why is that?

Has anyone successfully implemented this functionality? If so, can you please share your implementation? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the example code you are copying `deferringUpdates` is a property you would have to define on your `CLLocationManagerDelegate` object. It is not something defined or provided by the framework. That example code is not a complete implementation you can drop into your app.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a complete implementation?

Comment: No and I'm not even sure what you think that would look like. Deciding when to defer updates and by what time/distance depends on how your app uses that information. Someone else's implementation would not make sense in you app. Focus on understanding the example you have instead?